# How can I have new ~/.vnc/xstartup files be configured for normal desktop by default?

Tags: gnome, x11, vnc

When a user first runs `vncserver`, the following `~/.vnc/xstartup` file gets created:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
twm &
```

I want to modify the default file so that the following lines are uncommented:

```
unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

How should I go about this?

Comment: Just uncomment these two lines and restart your vncserver. Your default desktop will be started by vncserver

Comment: I want it to be done by default for all new users. I.e., change the default `~/.vnc/xstatup` that is created.

Comment: This is not clear from your question :) wait a second...

Comment: Any suggestions on how to make the question clearer (seems like you already have my answer but for others visiting the site :-)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a file `/etc/vnc/xstartup` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

And give it the read and execution permissions to all users:

```
chmod 0755 /etc/vnc/xstartup
```

Then this script will be executed by any user's vnc server