# TigerVNC Server Crashes when Client Connects

Tags: mate-desktop, tigervnc

I've installed "tigervnc-standalone-server" on my Raspberry PI 3 model b+ with Ubuntu Mate "Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS" (**not raspbian**), configure and set-up vncserver as system service.

I've edited file `~/.vnc/xstartup` like this :

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
#unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
#. /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
mate-session &
```

And configure `/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service` like this:

```bash
[Unit]
Description=Start TigerVNC server at startup
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=hamham
#Group=hamham
#WorkingDirectory=/home/hamham
#PAMName=login

PIDFile=/home/hamham/.vnc/%H:%i.pid
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -depth 24 -geometry 1280x800 -localhost no :%i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then enable like this :

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl enable vncserver@1.service
```

Check instance vnc running:

```
hamham@astroloutre:~$ vncserver -list
TigerVNC server sessions:
X DISPLAY # RFB PORT #  PROCESS ID
:1      5901        1202
```

Server-side all seems to be OK.
Log before try to connect from client:

```
hamham@astroloutre:~/.vnc$ more astroloutre\:1.log 
blueman-applet 16.10.04 WARNING  DiscvManager:109 update_menuitems: warning: Adapter is None

(process:2158): Indicator-Messages-WARNING **: 16:10:05.122: Unable to get a proxy on accounts service for touch settings: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.Accounts: Refusing activation, D-Bus is shutting down.
X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
Gdk-Message: 16:10:05.759: xfce4-terminal: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

mate-session[1438]: WARNING: Detected that screensaver has left the bus
Gdk-Message: 16:10:05.775: marco: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

Gdk-Message: 16:10:05.776: mate-settings-daemon: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

Gdk-Message: 16:10:05.780: mate-panel: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

Gdk-Message: 16:10:05.784: caja: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

Gdk-Message: 16:10:05.792: mate-session: Fatal IO error 104 (Connection reset by peer) on X server :1.

Gdk-Message: 16:10:05.797: update-notifier: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

Gdk-Message: 16:10:05.799: blueman-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.


** (process:2039): WARNING **: 16:10:05.818: exiting: service couldn't acquire, or lost ownership of, busname
Gdk-Message: 16:10:05.832: nm-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
Gdk-Message: 16:10:05.841: mate-maximus: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

Gdk-Message: 16:10:05.844: mate-screensaver: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.


(process:2085): indicator-application-service-WARNING **: 16:10:05.845: Name Lost
Indicator-Datetime-Message: 16:10:05.851: indicator-datetime exiting; failed/lost bus ownership
Gdk-Message: 16:10:05.851: evolution-alarm-notify: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.


(process:2110): indicator-sound-WARNING **: 16:10:05.885: Name lost or unable to acquire bus: com.canonical.indicator.sound
Gdk-Message: 16:10:05.893: blueman-tray: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.


Tue Aug  9 16:10:05 2022
 ComparingUpdateTracker: 0 pixels in / 0 pixels out
 ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:nan ratio)

(process:2158): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:10:05.917: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(process:2110): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:10:05.946: g_object_ref: assertion 'old_val > 0' failed

(process:2110): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:10:05.952: Error while sending AddMatch() message: The connection is closed

(process:2110): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:10:05.952: Error while sending AddMatch() message: The connection is closed

(process:2110): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:10:05.953: Error while sending AddMatch() message: The connection is closed

(process:2110): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:10:05.954: Error while sending AddMatch() message: The connection is closed

Xvnc TigerVNC 1.10.0 - built Apr  9 2020 06:49:31
Copyright (C) 1999-2019 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.rst)
See https://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 12008000, The X.Org Foundation


Tue Aug  9 16:10:19 2022
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5901
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
Impossible de se connecter au gestionnaire de sessions : Impossible de se connecter au gestionnaire de session : SESSION_MANAGER environment variable not defined
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/home/hamham/.cache/keyring-GR6SQ1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/home/hamham/.cache/keyring-GR6SQ1/ssh
mate-session[1439]: WARNING: Unable to find provider '' of required component 'dock'
Avertissement du gestionnaire de fenêtres : Log level 128: unsetenv() is not thread-safe and should not be used after threads are created
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/home/hamham/.cache/keyring-GR6SQ1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/home/hamham/.cache/keyring-GR6SQ1/ssh

(polkit-mate-authentication-agent-1:1989): polkit-mate-1-WARNING **: 16:11:51.621: Unable to determine the session we are in: No session for pid 1989
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/home/hamham/.cache/keyring-GR6SQ1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/home/hamham/.cache/keyring-GR6SQ1/ssh

(process:2103): indicator-sound-WARNING **: 16:11:53.080: volume-control-pulse.vala:735: unable to get pulse unix socket: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.PulseAudio1 was not provided by any .service fil
es

** (process:2012): WARNING **: 16:11:53.157: could not find the desktop file for 'org.gnome.Calendar.desktop'

(process:2012): Indicator-Datetime-WARNING **: 16:11:53.259: Unrecognized TZID: 'Etc/Utc'

(process:2012): Indicator-Datetime-WARNING **: 16:11:53.260: Unrecognized TZID: 'Etc/Utc'
caja-dropbox is not installed, doing nothing.
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/home/hamham/.cache/keyring-GR6SQ1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/home/hamham/.cache/keyring-GR6SQ1/ssh

(caja:1984): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:11:53.787: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.SessionManager.AlreadyRegistered: Unable to register client
no maximize: true
*** ERROR ***
TI:16:11:54 TH:0x2022320    FI:gpm-manager.c    FN:gpm_manager_systemd_inhibit,1786
 - Error in dbus - GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Permission denied
Traceback:
    mate-power-manager(+0x13716) [0x4de716]
    mate-power-manager(+0xcfbe) [0x4d7fbe]

** (light-locker:2175): ERROR **: 16:11:54.460: Environment variable XDG_SESSION_PATH not set. Is LightDM running?

** (xiccd:2172): WARNING **: 16:11:55.011: EDID is empty

** (xiccd:2172): CRITICAL **: 16:11:55.252: failed to create colord device: failed to obtain org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device auth
Initializing caja-open-terminal extension
mate-optimus-applet: launched.
  - nvidia-settings and prime-select not detected.
mate-optimus-applet: NVIDIA Optimus is not supported.

(mate-settings-daemon:1865): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:11:58.343: gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width -1 and height 28
blueman-applet 16.11.58 WARNING  PluginManager:147 __load_plugin: Not loading PPPSupport because its conflict has higher priority
INFO:root:The HUD is disabled via org.mate.hud in gsettings.
blueman-applet 16.12.00 WARNING  PluginManager:147 __load_plugin: Not loading DhcpClient because its conflict has higher priority
blueman-applet 16.12.00 WARNING  DiscvManager:109 update_menuitems: warning: Adapter is None
blueman-tray version 2.1.2 starting
There is an instance already running
[Debug] Autostart mode enabled. 
[Welcome] Welcome was autostarted but autostart is disabled. 
RuntimeError: object at 0xaedf9c68 of type RenameMenu is not initialized
RuntimeError: object at 0xaedf9c28 of type FolderColorMenu is not initialized
```

Desktop size, on my smartphone (not laptop), i'm trying to connect with RealVNC client,i put `192.168.1.5:5901` as address (or `192.168.1.5:1`), add password, try to connect and got the message:
`The connection closed unexpectedly`
Added in log `~/.vnc/astroloutre:1.log` :

```
Tue Aug  9 16:13:40 2022
 Connections: accepted: 192.168.1.22::40366
 SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8
 SConnection: Client requests security type VncAuth(2)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rdr::Exception'
terminate called recursively
(EE) 
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Caught signal 6 (Aborted). Server aborting
(EE) 
Gdk-Message: 16:13:48.236: evolution-alarm-notify: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

Gdk-Message: 16:13:48.236: caja: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

Gdk-Message: 16:13:48.238: xfce4-terminal: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
Gdk-Message: 16:13:48.239: update-notifier: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
Gdk-Message: 16:13:48.239: mate-panel: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

Gdk-Message: 16:13:48.262: mate-session: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

Gdk-Message: 16:13:48.271: marco: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

Gdk-Message: 16:13:48.296: mate-settings-daemon: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

(process:2103): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:13:48.631: g_object_ref: assertion 'old_val > 0' failed
```

It seems the problem is not about VNC but desktop manager but i dont know why and how to resolve it.
Thank you for help.

Comment: Does `/etc/vnc/xstartup` exist? Because if so `[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup` will replace your script with `xstartup`.

Comment: No it doesn't exist. Should i create it or replace this line in my `~/.vnc/xstartup` ?

Comment: I'd probably remove that line, to avoid surprises if the etc file ever does somehow exist.

Comment: Same problem. As seen as https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52976/536967 i'll create it and test again.